# How to call push notification button action with setTimeout function?

Tags: react-native

**I'm using react-native-push-notification package.**
I want to know how to call push notification button action with setTimeout function.

```js
const isGood = false;
const options = {
//...
actions: isGood
      ? [`pause`]
      : [
          `pause`,
          `done`,
          `skip`,
        ],
//...
}
PushNotification.localNotification(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [README](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#readme) of the project?
Or looked in to the [example](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/example/NotifService.js) they provide?

If you did I think this medium article:
[**"Implementing React Native Push Notifications in Android Apps"**](https://medium.com/@Jscrambler/implementing-react-native-push-notifications-in-android-apps-7e0234dee7b7)
might be a help for you.